# How to combine these two js actions

Tags: javascript, ajax, seadragon

I hope this is a fairly simple problem.

The first line switches to a new deep zoom image. The second line zooms into the image. Is it possible to both switch and zoom in one click?

1.

```
<a style="font-size: 80%;" onclick="switchTo(event,'http://www.diyacu.com/storage/deep-zoom/bladder/dzc_output.xml');" href="#">
   <strong>Skin</strong>
</a>
```

2.

```
<a class="sdNav" href="#" sdX="0.225873075478783" sdY="0.0918137438978595" sdZ="15">
  BL1
</a>
```

Thanks so much!

Andrew.

Comment: Do you mean Javascript?Please be more specific about your problem

Comment: Agrees with @peraueb8921. I don't see any Java code in the original question.

Comment: Yes, Javascript. Sorry I'm fumbling blindly through this, not being a coder myself.

Comment: OK, I've corrected your tags to reduce confusion.